# Bootstrap Collapse conflicts with multiple jquery and bootstrap.js; require.js

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, requirejs, amd

I have a web app (we'll call it WA1) that uses RequireJS to load jQuery and Bootstrap.js. This app gets built into a single file (main.built.js) and runs inside an element of a page on a different web app (WA2).

(WA1 can run standalone as well -- without getting built into WA2)

WA2 loads jQuery and Bootstrap.js normally, but the main.built.js file also contains jQuery and Bootstrap.js.

Part of the UI of WA1 contains a Bootstrap collapse element. The actions of collapsing/uncollapsing are triggered by data attributes put in the html. If you look at [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wSPXP/16/), the element that is supposed to collapse cannot collapse -- I think because the collapse action is getting triggered twice - once by the listeners in the WA2 Bootstrap.js file, and once by the listeners in the main.built.js file.

I would like the collapse to function correctly, but I do not have the option of removing Bootstrap.js from WA2. Nor do I have the option to use RequireJS in WA2.

Is there a way for WA1 to not load jQuery and Bootstrap.js with require.js, but allow modules loaded through require.js to use jQuery and Bootstrap that would get loaded normally (without RequireJS)? If not, can jQuery's `$.noconflict()` help at all? I'm not really familiar with how that works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ended up doing the following:

- Before I load any require modules (including jQuery), I check if jQuery already exists (it does exist if I'm running in WA2). If do, i set `$isloaded` to `true`.
- After the require bootstrap.js is loaded, if `$isloaded` is `true`, i set `$.fn.collapse = function(){}`.

This way, only the $.fn.collapse function in the WA2-loaded jquery/bootstrap will do something. Feels kind of hacky, but it worked.

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/wSPXP/17/

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way to do what I understand you want to do. The `console.log` statements are just there to check what is going on. If I add the following segment of code just before your `require` call in your fiddle (and after the `require.config` call), then the collapsing element works fine:

```
(function () {
    define("jquery-fake", [], function () { 
        console.log("jquery-fake"); 
        // Just return the already loaded jQuery.
        return $; 
    });

    define("bootstrap-fake", ["jquery"], function () { 
        console.log("bootstrap-fake");
        // Nothing to be done here.
    });

    var map = {};

    if ($)
        map.jquery = "jquery-fake";

    if ($.fn.popover)
        map.bootstrap = "bootstrap-fake";

    require.config({ map: { "*": map } });
})();
```

The above won't work if you don't *also* remove jQuery from the list of "External Resources". Right now, it is loaded twice *before* RequireJS starts loading anything.

Requisites:

1. This must appear after your initial `require.config` call but before you start loading anything.
2. The jQuery and Bootstrap that are loaded for WA2 must **already** be loaded before this code runs.

How it works:

1. It detects whether jQuery is loaded by checking that `$` is set.
2. It detects whether Bootstrap is loaded by checking whether `$.fn.popover` exists. I don't know of a sanctioned way to check whether Bootstrap has been loaded. I've checked the code and did not see a `$.fn.bootstrap` or anything similar which would presumably be unique to Bootstrap. It does set a `popover` method so that's what I use.
3. When these are detected to be already present, the map for "*" is populated so that when `jquery` is required `jquery-fake` is loaded instead, and similarly for `bootstrap`.
4. The two fake modules are those you see defined early in the code. They don't actually load anything.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wSPXP/18/)

Comment: can you share a jsfiddle with this working? I added your snipped to my fiddle but the collapse element still does not work correctly.

Comment: Finally got around to implementing this pattern myself! Much better approach, nice work +1

Answer (score 0):

I've had a similar problem in the past. It annoys me to this day that I've encountered it, but I'm glad to know I'm not the only one.

The way I got around it was, exactly as you've identified, to use [`$.noConflict(true)`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.noconflict/).

You will need two require config scripts.

For WA1, you'll need to configure require in the normal manner. This will enable you to run it as a standalone web app, independent of WA2:

```
require.config({
    paths: {
        'jquery': '//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js',
        //...
    }
});
```

For WA2, you'll need to configure require like so:

```
require.config({
    paths: {
        'jquery': 'src/jquery-no-conflict',
        'jquery-src': '//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js',
        //...
    }
});
```

In jquery-no-conflict.js, we load jQuery, but revert the global `$` to the version loaded by WA2:

```
define(['jquery-src'], function ($) {

    //unload the newly loaded version of jQuery
    $.noConflict(true);

    //return the original version
    return $;
});
```

Now, when loaded from WA2, your `define` functions in WA1 will call jquery-no-conflict.js

The only thing I don't like about this pattern is that your HTML for WA1 now contains two references to jQuery, although the global `$` will still point to the first jQuery instance loaded.

Although I haven't tried it, presumably you can apply a similar pattern using Bootstrap's [noConflict](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#js-noconflict)

Please let me know how you get on.

Comment: This is a good workaround if I were calling bootstrap.js functions within my modules, but I think the problem is that clicking on an element with the data-toggle attribute still triggers both jQuerys, since the trigger is coming from a click event in the DOM rather than inside one of my modules.